# Handle JSON response from POST-request

Tags: json, node.js, http-post

Im having trouble with reading JSON-response when sending a POST request to a oauth server. This is my code for POST:

```
var request = require("request");
var querystring = require('querystring');

var postData={
    grant_type: 'code',
    code: code,
    redirect_uri: uri,
    nonce: nonce
};

request.post({
    uri: oauth_token_uri    ,
    headers:
    {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': oauth_code
    },
    body: querystring.stringify(postData)
}, function(err,res, body){
    console.log("BODY:" + res.body);
    console.log("BODY: " + body);
    console.log("Access Token:" + res.body.access_token);
    console.log("Access Token:" + body.access_token);
});
```

This is the output in the console:

```
BODY:{"access_token":"somecode","refresh_token":"somecode","expires_in":900,"token_type":"bearer","id_token":"someTokenID"}
BODY:{"access_token":"somecode","refresh_token":"somecode","expires_in":900,"token_type":"bearer","id_token":"someTokenID"}
Access Token:undefined
Access Token: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following,

```
request.post({
    uri: oauth_token_uri    ,
    headers:
    {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': oauth_code
    },
    body: querystring.stringify(postData)
}, function(err,res, body){
    var parsedResponseBody = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("Access Token:" + parsedResponseBody.access_token);
});
```

You are getting the response in `String` format. You will first need to parse that response in JSON object.